# mdframed: how to put the optional argument of a theorem-like environment between brackets?

Tags: theorems, mdframed, optional-arguments

### The classical case

With the classical `\newtheorem` command of `amsthm`, one gets the following result for **optional arguments**:
[image]
from this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Riemann]
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### The `mdframed` case

I would like to get a similar result with `mdframed`:**the optional argument between brackets, but no change of font and no dot at the end**. But by default, here is what I get:

[image]

from the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFramedTheoremStyle}{%
frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
linecolor=red,
linewidth=4pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
frametitleaboveskip=5pt,
skipbelow=0pt,
font=\itshape
}

\mdtheorem[style=myFramedTheoremStyle]{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Riemann]
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### What I have found so far

In the documentation, I have found the following options (of the `\mdfdefinestyle` command):

> theoremseparator, theoremtitlefont and theoremspace

but there seems to be to attribute for defining what comes after the optional argument. I am looking for an option of the `\mdfdefinestyle` command which could be called `theoremtextafter`.

### My question

I hope something like that exists. Do you know if it is the case? If not, is it possible to find an easy solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the official way of doing it, but here is a *hack* that does the job which:

- applies `theoremtitlefont=\normalfont` to get the correct font in the title
- renames the `mdframed` theorem to be `MDtheorem`, and
- creates a `\newenvironment` called `theorem` which inserts the desired `(` and `)` to the theorem name before passing it on to the `MDtheorem`.
- creates a `\newenvironment` called `theorem*` to provide the same functionality *without* the numbering.

[image]

### Notes:

- For the starred variant `theorem*` the `mdframe` style `theoremtitlefont=\normalfont`, did not seem sufficient so had to add a manual `\normalfont`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFramedTheoremStyle}{%
    frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
    linecolor=red,
    linewidth=4pt,
    innertopmargin=0pt,
    innerbottommargin=10pt,
    innerleftmargin=10pt,
    innerrightmargin=10pt,
    frametitleaboveskip=5pt,
    skipbelow=0pt,
    theoremtitlefont=\normalfont,
    font=\itshape
}

\mdtheorem[style=myFramedTheoremStyle]{MDtheorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*{\Title}{}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\begin{MDtheorem}}{\begin{MDtheorem}[(#1)]}%
}{%
    \end{MDtheorem}%
}%

\newenvironment{theorem*}[1][]{%
    % Required `\normalfont` in `MDtheorem*`, but not in the `MDtheorem` environment
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\begin{MDtheorem*}}{\begin{MDtheorem*}[\normalfont(#1)]}%
}{%
    \end{MDtheorem*}%
}%


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Riemann]
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}[Riemann]
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem*}

\begin{theorem*}
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful, with this hack, you'll also have to "re-define" `\begin{theorem*}`.

Comment: Your hack does not work, unfortunately... If you type `\begin{theorem}
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}` you will still have the `:` after `Theorem`

Comment: @Colas: Fixed to handle using it without the optional environment (as per your answer).  Also defined `theorem*` variant.

Comment: I found a bug in mdframed, related to this issue of optional arguments. You might be interested, http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179790/8323

Answer (score 0):

Based on Peter's answer,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myFramedTheoremStyle}{%
frametitlealignment=\raggedright,
linecolor=red,
linewidth=4pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=10pt,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=10pt,
frametitleaboveskip=5pt,
skipbelow=0pt,
theoremtitlefont=\normalfont,
font=\itshape
}

\mdtheorem[style=myFramedTheoremStyle]{MDtheorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*{\Title}{}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{\begin{MDtheorem}}%
    {\begin{MDtheorem}[(#1)]}
}{%
    \end{MDtheorem}%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Riemann]
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
Let $X$... Nulla egestas congue ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum est. Quisque ut urna lorem. Sed non aliquet sem, quis sollicitudin ante. 
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]